# Asking specific person for answer or clarify his question in order to help me with my problem

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've asked a question which might be hard to answer because it's concerns right-to -left script which I guess is not the most often used by TeX users. :) The question is about sorting tools for Arabic glossary. I've found another question, where the issue is that Farsi glossary was sorted by Arabic alphabet order and not Farsi. For me it means that that person achieved what I want to achieve, but since there is no code in the question, I don't know how he did.

Is there a way to ask this person to see my question or to post MWE in his own question? Is it not against the StackExchange rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply post a comment to his question with your query, that person will see it in his or her SE inbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)